# Ubuntu partitioning for new Windows Install

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I have the entire harddrive on my computer partitioned for my ubuntu install. Arkham Asylum is tempting me to get back into gaming. Is there a way to take half of my harddrive, and create a separate partition to install Windows Vista on without losing the data I have on my ubuntu partition?

Harddrive is less than 25% filled.

Comment: Did you try this?  Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a backup of your data to some external media.

Then boot up your Ubuntu install CD (select the "Try without installing" option at the CD boot menu) and go to *System > Administration > Partition Editor*. This will run `gparted`.

You can then resize the Ubuntu partition and create a new NTFS partition for Windows. Once that's done, reboot and install Windows Vista and make sure that you select the partition that says it's NTFS and empty (otherwise, your data gets erased).

After installing Windows Vista, reboot with the Ubuntu CD again (Try without installing again) and follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows#Using%20the%20Ubuntu%20Desktop/Live%20CD).

Comment: actually you can install Gparted instead of using a install cd. Just sudo apt-get install gparted, or install it via Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 6):

You can use gparted to reduce the size of partitions and to create new ones. But you should also have a live cd handy to reinstall grub after windows has overwritten it. Also, I would recommend a full backup before you let the windows installer touch anything.

Comment: Here's some reasonably simple instructions for recovering grub http://ranacse05.wordpress.com/2008/01/12/grub-recovery-after-installing-windows-xp/